# Ember-cli customize test-body layout (content-for)

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, qunit, ember-qunit, ember-testing

In the latest version of ember-cli-qunit, the test-body.html template looks like this...

```
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>

<div id="ember-testing-container">
  <div id="ember-testing"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to customize this without changing the source directly in the package? This might sound a bit nit-picky, but I'd prefer a slightly different layout when running tests in the browser :).

I can't seem to find much documentation on overriding this template.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% on this, but I believe you can just drop test-body.html in your `app/` folder and it will use this instead in the same way that it uses index.html

Comment: Seemed like a logical idea, but a app/test-body.html file was no good unfortunately :(.

Comment: Damn.  There is a way to hook the content-for helper in your environment.js file, or you might be able to edit tests/index.html and replace {{content-for 'test-body'}} with your own code.  I'm not sure how much dynamic stuff happens there though.  I'll take a look at getting you a complete solution a bit later :-)